# IOS build fails because of linking

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

As you can see in the picture, my build fails. I suspect it's something regarding the link. I used `react-native link`, not pods. Besides that, I tried a clean build and deleting the DerivedData folder. Any chance somebody may help? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hi have you linked the Firebase binary to the project yet, under `Link Binary with Libraries`?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. It wasn't the correct one but gave me the idea to solve it. What I had to do was to point in header search towards the Firebase.h and then link all the frameworks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use cocoapods for dependency management,
if you already using it then remove all pods and add it again / update all pods

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I solved it by linking every framework of Firebase manually.

Comment: Please I have this error with cordova so I don't control the code, can you write how remove all pods and add it again / update all pods? thanks

Comment: if you  have a podfile, then you can see all the third party libraries here,
first comment each third party libray with  # symbol and run "pod install" via simulator it will remove all third party libraries from the project , after that uncomment remove # from pod file and again run "pod install"